# How Do I Change the Application Mapped to Open in Terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, terminator

I have appended Open in Terminal to my right-click context menu which by default, opens up a terminal window at the selected location. I would like to replace the default terminal window with Terminator.

This is linux, I know it's achievable so I'd rather ask, How is this achieved?

Comment: What plugin/etc did you use to add that to the context menu? You might try following the guide [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/set-the-default-terminal-emulator-on-ubuntu-linux/) to set Terminator as your default terminal.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal`